# rails query Virtual columns is not exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have write down this query in rails 4

```
result = User.select("id, (3959 * acos( cos( radians("+latitude+") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians("+longitude+") ) + sin( radians(" +latitude +") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )  as distants")
```

when I inspect the data, it does show me distants virtual fields? How can i display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually present in the `ActiveRecord` object. You can get it by accessing it as a key of that object:

`result = User.select("id, (3959 * acos( cos( radians("+latitude+") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians("+longitude+") ) + sin( radians(" +latitude +") ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )  as distants")`

```
result.each do |user|
  puts user['distants']
end
```

Comment: Thanks @amit Thawait, I working fine, what when i implement abort(result.inspect) then it didn't show me distants, Why so?